# .each() not working with condition

Tags: jquery

Here is what am looking for with more description and my code is below:
for example when pendingOrder[i].LineItemId =32, it should get only that particular row data, not sure how to add condition to get that paticular row index which matches pendingOrder[i].LineItemId =32

```
$.each(pendingOrder, function(i, lineitemdata) {
               if(pendingOrder[i].LineItemId == lineItemId);
                 {
                       return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Is this a typo or in your real code: `if (this["LineItemId") == 'lineitemvalue'`

Comment: if (this["LineItemId"] == 'lineitemvalue') maybe? But your code still makes no sense.

Comment: if there is a match then return false to come out of the loop

Comment: This way? `if (pendinglineitem.LineItemId == 'lineitemvalue')`

Comment: Would be helpful if you post the pendingorder object structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see more of the logic to be sure of what you are trying to do here, but right off I can see that you have a syntax error:

```
if (this["LineItemId") == 'lineitemvalue'
```

you have a **[** when I believe it should be a **(**

try:

```
if (this("LineItemId") == 'lineitemvalue'
```

and see if you have any more luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code :

```
$.each(pendingorder, function(i,pendinglineitem){
    if (this["LineItemId"] == 'lineitemvalue'){
         pendingorder=this;
    }
});
```

Here `this["LineItemId"] == 'lineitemvalue'` condition can be somewhat wrong. Check the variables, it should be :

```
if (pendinglineitem == 'lineitemvalue'){
```

Hope, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Here is what am looking for with more description and my code is below: for example when pendingOrder[i].LineItemId =32, it should get only that particular row data, not sure how to add condition to get that paticular row index which matches pendingOrder[i].LineItemId =32

$.each(pendingOrder, function(i, lineitemdata) {
               if(pendingOrder[i].LineItemId == lineItemId);
                 {
                       return false;
}
});

Comment: Your if condition is bit confusing. Please share the `pendingOrder` object detail.